# Alert when tab on age

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got multiple forms. I have 5 text fields.

```
<form action="action_page.php">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname"br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname""><br>
  Age:<br>
  <input type="text" name="age"br>
  State:<br>
  <input type="text" name="state"br>
  Profession:<br>
  <input type="text" name="profession"br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

While the user is tabbing through the fields, how can I set an alert when focused on the `age` field?

Comment: You have a `invalid-markup`

Comment: There is `onfocus` event specifically for this...

Comment: Becky, do you want to capture only `TAB` key focus event or normal `focus` event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> While the user is tabbing through the fields, how can I set an alert when focused on the age field?

The other answers do not answer this question. OP want to show alert only when tabbing through fields and when `age` field is focused.

```
$(':text').eq($(':text[name="age"]').index('form :text')).on('keyup', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 9) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            alert('Focused');
        });
    }
});
```

```js
$(':text').eq($(':text[name="age"]').index('form :text')).on('keyup', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 9) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            alert('Focused');
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="action_page.php">
    First name:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" br> Last name:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname">
    <br> Age:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="age" br> State:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="state" br> Profession:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="profession" br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: @RayonDabre I think OP wants to capture `focus` event on `age` only when tabbing i.e. Pressing TAB key. Let's wait for OP to respond

Comment: @Becky Thanks for confirmation, can you edit the question to explain this

Comment: @Tushar, With time some people develop this ability to understand the query which is bot specified.. :) #RESPECT

Answer (score 4):

You can use focus event:

```
$("input[name = 'age']").focus(function() {
  alert( "focused on age inputbox." );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on('focus',"input[name = 'age']",function(){

alert('Entered age field ');

})
```

Below is the working fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/5ud8zm06/1/

Answer (score 1):

Hi kindly check https://jsfiddle.net/snvurmez/  you need to use focus() function

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name='age']").on('focus', function(){
    alert('focus on age tab');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the attribute selector to select the input by it's name.

Then bind a event based on the focus:

```
$('[name=age]'.on('focus', function() {
     alert('Age is clicked');
});
```